# Asterisk * is not accepting in Case statement in bash

Tags: bash, escape-characters, case

Asterisk is not accepting in my case statement, My case statement is below, i tried escaping with \ " ',but no luck.
can you correct me where i am wrong here.

```
case $tdat in
    *['\*''!'@#$%^"'*'"-+]* )  echo "Special charters are not allowed" 
     usage
     exit 100 ;;
```

Comment: You may want to use the pattern `*[[:punct:]]*` instead. To match a `*` anywhere in a string, you may use `*[*]*` or `*\**` or `*'*'*` or `*"*"*`.  Not turning this into an answer until we know what's in `$tdat` and what the user is trying to achieve.

Comment: Another idea would be to use a pattern that employs the characters that you _do_ want the string to contain, but inverted: `*[![:alnum:][:blank:]_]*` (matches a character that isn't an alphanumeric, space, tab, or underscore, somewhere in a string).  Again, we don't quite know what you're after.

Comment: @Kusalananda  $tdat date  in mmddyyyy format. Used this *"*"* in  case and it is working Fine ,Thanks Alot!!!!

Answer (score 1):

According to comments, you want to validate that a string in `$tdat` is a date in `MMDDYYYY` format.

Your current issue is to write out a diagnostic message and exit if the given string contains a variety of illegal characters, mostly punctuation characters.

I would personally use `*[[:punct:]]*` to try to see whether a string contains a punctuation character.  The `[:punct:]` character class is the set `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ ``.

In this *particular* case, given that we want the string in `$tdat` to be eight digits, exactly:

```bsh
case $tdat in
    *[![:digit:]]*)
        echo 'Incorrect, contains non-digit'
        exit 1
        ;;
    ????????)
        echo 'Correct, contains eight digits exactly'
        ;;
    *)
        echo 'Incorrect, contains some other number of digits, not eight'
        exit 1
esac
```

In the `bash` shell, you could obviously also use a regular expression test:

```bsh
if [[ $tdat =~ ^[[:digit:]]{8}$ ]]; then
    echo 'Correct, contains eight digits exactly'
else
    echo 'Incorrect, contains something that is not just eight digits'
    exit 1
fi
```

After deciding that `$tdat` is a string of eight digits, the next task is to figure out whether it's *a valid date*.  This is outside the scope of this question.